# Format a number to replace a decimal with space

Tags: javascript, numbers, format, acrobat

I have a field on a form in Adobe that automatically sums the values from six other fields.  The sum results in a decimal "." being placed so there are always 2 digits following.

The values in each of the six fields are typed in using a space to act as decimal place, as in "14 50" = $14.50 (see image).

The resulting sum is correct, but I'd like to add custom formatting that will replace the "." with a space, so that the sum in my example would read "87 00" rather than "87.00"

[image: Image 1 - Summed fields with correct sum at bottom, currently with decimal]

The javascript must be code that will work in the Adobe Pro custom format option for the field.

[image: Image 2 - Adobe format options]

Answer (score 0):

```
var num = 87.27;
var formatted;

if (num % 1 === 0) {
  formatted = num.toString() +' 00';
} else {
  formatted = num.toString().replace('.', ' ');  
}
```